# Item vermelho na tela impedir submit - Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma `view` com 3 `divs` e 20 `input number` em cada linha da minha div e um `input submit`. Cada linha vem do meu banco.

(Para este exemplo usarei somente 3 `inputs number`).

Essas minhas `divs` são como se fossem 3 categorias de qualquer coisa, ou seja, vou exemplificar aqui em NOTAS ESCOLARES e as CATEGORIAS serão os ALUNOS.

> Como utilizo ASP .NET MVC para fazer a VIEW então nao utilizo `<input>`, mas sim `@Html.TextBox`.. Como, para mim, não faz diferença eu escrever com o @Html, pois a duvida não se refere a isso, então escrevi com `<input>` para facilitar.

```js
function validacao(contagem){
  var botao = false;
  var cor = "black;"
  var total = 0;
  
  /*
  Alem da contagem, eu passo outros parametros, para que eu consiga realizar a
  minha soma, então as removi, pois nao acho necessario para minha duvida.
  */
  
  
  if (total < 9) {
    botao = false;
    cor = "black";
  } else {
    botao = true;
    cor = "red"
  }
    
  for (var i = 0; i <= contagem; i++) {
    $("#meusInputs"+i).css('color', cor);
    $("#btn-salvar").prop('disabled', botao);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Media de Notas</h3>
<div class="form-inline">
<div class="form-inline">
<p> Maria </p>
<input type="number" class = "form-control" id="meusInputs"+contagem onblur="validacao("+@contagem+")">
<input type="number" class = "form-control" id="meusInputs"+contagem onblur="validacao("+@contagem+")">
<input type="number" class = "form-control" id="meusInputs"+contagem onblur="validacao("+@contagem+")">
</div>
<div class="form-inline">
<p> Joao </p>
<input type="number" class = "form-control" id="meusInputs"+contagem onblur="validacao("+@contagem+")">
<input type="number" class = "form-control" id="meusInputs"+contagem onblur="validacao("+@contagem+")">
<input type="number" class = "form-control" id="meusInputs"+contagem onblur="validacao("+@contagem+")">
</div>
<br/>
contagem++ // Usado no foreach da minha view ASP .NET MVC <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Salvar" id="btn-salvar">
```

Durante o preenchimento desta minha pagina, eu realizo uma validação em que a soma de uma linha não ultrapasse de 8, se ultrapassar o texto de todos os `inputs number` daquela linha passa a ser vermelho e o `submit` fica desabilitado.

Está validação eu realizo, OBRIGATORIAMENTE, no onblur de CADA `input number`.
Porem, conforme eu vou seguindo no preenchimento e a validação (dos outros `inputs number`) se tornam corretas (ou seja, abaixo de 8), meu `submit` volta a ficar habilitado e a minha duvida é:

> Como eu faço para que, se existir pelo menos um `input number` com o texto em vermelho, o meu `submit` continue DESABILITADO?

Comment: Cara vc foi bem claro na explicação. Mas sem o seu JS fica impossível de te responder. Coloque tb seu JS ou jQuery etc

Comment: Esta parte do JS e JQuery pode ficar um pouco confusa, mas tentarei te explicar com o que nao entender

Comment: Os valores são números inteiros?

Comment: @Sam, sim, são numero inteiros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para facilitar, coloque uma classe em cada linha (coloquei `linhas`). Assim você consegue seleciona-las e fazer um laço nelas, podendo utilizar o `.each` do jQuery. A ideia é percorrer cada linha e somar os inputs por índice (`:eq(0)` são os primeiros, `:eq(1)` os segundos etc.). Se os valores forem maior do que 8, desabilita o botão e muda as cores (veja comentários no código):

```js
$("[type=number]").on("blur", function(){
   
   // seleciona as linhas
   var linhas = $(".linhas");
   
   // número de inputs por linha
   var num_inps = 3;
   
   // desabilita começa com false
   var desabilita = false;
   
   for(var x=0; x<num_inps; x++){

      // valor da soma começa com 0
      var soma = 0;
      
      // percorre cada linha
      linhas.each(function(){
         soma += Number($("input:eq("+x+")", this).val()) || 0;
      });

      // se for maior que 8 a soma dos campos da linha
      if(soma > 8) desabilita = true;

      // altera as cores
      linhas.each(function(){
         $("input:eq("+x+")", this).css("color", soma > 8 ? "red" : "black");
      });
      
   }
      
   // desabilita ou habilita o botão de for true ou false
   $("[type=submit]").prop("disabled", desabilita ? true : false);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Media de Notas</h3>
<div class="form-inline linhas">
   <p> Maria </p>
   <input type="number" class = "form-control"><input type="number" class = "form-control"><input type="number" class = "form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-inline linhas">
   <p> Joao </p>
   <input type="number" class = "form-control"><input type="number" class = "form-control"><input type="number" class = "form-control">
</div>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Salvar">
```

> Não precisa usar onblur e id's nos campos.

Comment: mas por exemplo, na linha Maria, blz fez a validação, pintou de vermelho e botao desabilitado, na linha do Joao, blz fez a validação, nao pintou de vermelho e botao habilitado, eu consigo salvar, mesmo com a primeira linha (maria) estando vermelha? (isso nao pode acontecer), pq eu passei pela linha do Joao e o botao voltou a ser habilitado

Comment: Enquanto tiver linhas vermelhas o botão permanece desabilitado. Pode testar aí.

Comment: blz vou testar, obrigado até então

Comment: Esta informação pode te deixar bravo, rs, eu usei como linhas para facilitar pois achava que nao seria um fator importante, na realidade eu preciso somar as colunas, ou seja, nota1 da maria com nota1 do joao, isso atrapalha muuuuito a sua solução? Se sim, como o erro foi meu, eu adapto o que você me mandou e ta tudo bem :)

Comment: Mas as cores são por colunas tb?

Comment: sim, são sim, mas as cores eu consegui fazer, pq nao depende das outras colunas, entao quando a soma dos itens da coluna 1 forem menores q 9, o texto volta a ser preto, o problema é o botao mesmo

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Dá uma testada.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86760/discussion-between-leooso-and-sam).